# Swift 1D Dictionary to 2D

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary, swift3

I've got a little problem in understanding two-dimensional dictionaries. My function has to return dictionary for UITableView with sections. 1 template type can have multiple template strings. So when in `fetchedData` there are 2 or more texts with similar types, they have to be in array [String] with 1 key - String. 
The code below is absolutely correct from the complier point of view. As for me smth is wrong, but nice auto-completions make me think that everything is OK.
Obviously it returns an empty dictionary `[:]`

```
func fetchTemplates() -> Dictionary<String, [String]> {
    var templates: Dictionary<String, [String]> = [:]
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Template> = Template.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor.init(key: "templateType", ascending: true)]
    let fetchedData = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    if (!fetchedData.isEmpty) {
        for templateItem in fetchedData {
            templates[templateItem.templateType!]?.append(templateItem.templateText!)
        }
        return templates
    }
    else {
        return templates
    }
}
```

P.S. `fetchedData` returns:

```
<Template: 0x003281h4> (entity: Template; id: 0x003281h4 <x-coredata:///Template/> ; data: {
    templateText = "Example";
    templateType = "First";
})
```

Comment: Side note: there's no need to do that check for `!fetchedData.isEmpty`. If it is empty, then the for loop will iterate 0 times, meaning it would just be skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies on this line:

```
templates[templateItem.templateType!]?.append(templateItem.templateText!)
```

`templates` was initialized with this line: `var templates: Dictionary<String, [String]> = [:]`. At this point, `templates` is an empty dictionary.

Let's break that line down into the steps that happen, in chronological order:

1. `templateItem.templateType` is accessed, and force unwrapped. A crash will occur if it's `nil`.
2. `templateItem.templateType!` is used as a key into the `templates` dictionary. This will always return `nil`. The dictionary is empty, thus is has no values for any keys, including this one.
3. `?.append()` is called, on the condition that it's not being called on `nil`. If it's called on `nil`, nothing will happen.

3 is the cause of your issue. You need to initialize a new array if one doesn't exist for the key yet:

```
func fetchTemplates() -> Dictionary<String, [String]> {
    var templates: Dictionary<String, [String]> = [:]
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Template> = Template.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor.init(key: "templateType", ascending: true)]
    let fetchedData = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    if (!fetchedData.isEmpty) { //see note 2
        for templateItem in fetchedData {
           let type = templateItem.templateType!
           var array = templates[type] ?? [] //see note 1
           array!.append(templateItem.templateText!)
           templates[type] = array
        }
        return templates
    }
    else {
        return templates
    }
}
```

This function can be simplified:

```
func fetchTemplates() -> [String : [String]] {
    let fetchRequest = Template.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(key: "templateType", ascending: true)]

    let fetchedData = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)

    var templates = [String, [String]]()
    for templateItem in fetchedData {
        let type = templateItem.templateType!
        templates[type] = (templates[text] ?? []) + [templateItem.templateText!]
    }
    return templates
}
```

and reduce can be used instead:

```
func fetchTemplates() -> [String : [String]] { //see note 3
    let fetchRequest = Template.fetchRequest() //see note 4
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(key: "templateType", ascending: true)] //see note 5

    let fetchedData = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)

    return fetchedData.reduce([String, [String]]()){templates, templateItem in
        (templates[templateItem.tempalteText!] ?? []) + [templateItem.templateText!]
    } //see note 6
}
```

## Notes

1. if `template[text]` is not `nil`, it's assigned to `array`. Otherwise, a new array (`[]`) is assigned to `array.
2. this check is unnecessary
3. `Dictionary<String, [String]>` can be written as just `[String : [String]]`
4. No need for an explicit type signiture
5. `X.init()` can be written as just `X()`
6. The emptiness check is unnecessary, and the whole `for` loop can be changed into a `reduce` call.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is:

`templates[templateItem.templateType!]` is always `nil` because the dictionary is empty.

Therefore nothing can be appended.